# How to have one line for duplicates value in igraph plot in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I have a data frame with three columns that want to have igraph plot for it. The first column has duplicate values when I visualize by `igraph` it makes two lines. But, I want to be just one line for duplicates values.

this is the reproducible data:

```
dput(sample)
structure(list(NMSUKU = c("Aceh/ Achin/ Akhir/ Asji/ A-Tse/ Ureung Aceh", 
"Alas", "Aneuk Jamee", "Gayo", "Gayo Lut", "Gayo Luwes", "Gayo Serbe Jadi", 
"Kluet", "Sigulai", "Simeulue", "Simeulue", "Simeulue", "Singkil", 
"Singkil", "Tamiang"), TopLang = c("Aceh/ Acheh/ Achi ", "Alas ", 
"Aceh Jamee ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", "Gajo/ Gayo ", 
"Aceh Kluet ", "ERROR  TopCol out of range ", "Long Bano/ Simalur/ Simeuloe/ Simeulue/ Simulul ", 
"Aceh Simeleu Barat ", "Aceh Simeleu Tengah ", "Aceh Hulu Singkil ", 
"Aceh Hulu Singkil ", "Tamiang "), Ethnicity = c("1_Aceh/ Achin/ Akhir/ Asji/ A-Tse/ Ureung Aceh  ", 
"2_Alas  ", "3_Aneuk Jamee  ", "4_Gayo  ", "6_Gayo Luwes  ", 
"5_Gayo Lut  ", "7_Gayo Serbe Jadi  ", "8_Kluet  ", "NA  ", "10_Simeulue  ", 
"10_Simeulue  ", "10_Simeulue  ", "11_Singkil  ", "17_Batak Pakpak Dairi  ", 
"12_Tamiang  ")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

I ran these codes:

```
m <- as.matrix(sample)
g <- graph_from_edgelist(rbind(m[,1:2], m[,2:3]), directed = TRUE)
l <- layout_with_sugiyama(g)
plot(g, layout=-l$layout[,2:1],
     edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
     vertex.size = 2.5,
     vertex.color = "grey",
     vertex.label.dist = 1,
     edge.arrow.width = 1.5,
     edge.width = seq(0.5,0.08),
     edge.lty = "solid",
     edge.color = "gray",
     vertex.label.cex = 0.7,
     is.rm = TRUE,
     vertex.label.color = "black")
```

This is what I got
[image]

I want to have one line from **Singkil to Aceh Hulu Singkil**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`igraph::simplify()` is great for this.

Modifying your `plot()` call as follows draws only a single line where you previously had two.

```
plot(simplify(g), layout=-l$layout[,2:1],
     edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
    vertex.size = 2.5,
     vertex.color = "grey",
     vertex.label.dist = 1,
     edge.arrow.width = 1.5,
     edge.width = seq(0.5,0.08),
     edge.lty = "solid",
     edge.color = "gray",
     vertex.label.cex = 0.7,
     is.rm = TRUE,
     vertex.label.color = "black")
```

If you add a weight vector to the `igraph` object before simplifying the edges count is aggregated in the edge weight and you can use it in the visualization. Below will result in a slightly thicker line for the edge in question.

```
E(g)$weight <- 1
g <- simplify(g, edge.attr.comb = "sum")
plot(g, layout=-l$layout[,2:1],
     edge.arrow.size = 0.1,
     vertex.size = 2.5,
     vertex.color = "grey",
     vertex.label.dist = 1,
     edge.arrow.width = 1.5,
     edge.width = E(g)$weight,
     edge.lty = "solid",
     edge.color = "gray",
     vertex.label.cex = 0.7,
     is.rm = TRUE,
     vertex.label.color = "black")
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! the codes work for sample data but when I ran it I got the same problem. In the second codes I got this error : `Error in simplify(g, edge.attr.comb = "sum") : 
  unused argument (edge.attr.comb = "sum")` I do not know why.

Comment: Most likely you have loaded `purrr` after igraph. `purrr` has a `simplify()` command of its own, as do a few other packages. You can ensure to use the correct command by explicitly asking for the igraph command with `igraph::simplify(g)`.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph is directed, you can use `unique()` on the edgelist, before turning it into an `igraph` object to "simplify" your graph.

```
g <- graph_from_edgelist(unique(rbind(m[, 1:2], m[, 2:3])), directed = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thomasls Coding, thanks for answering, How can make it an **interactive**?

Comment: @user14828029 You can use `tkplot` instead of `plot` here to get the interactive plot.